# Howto open firewall ports during installation?

Tags: java, windows, firewall, install4j, windows-firewall

How can I open Windows Firewall ports during installation with install4j?
I found this solution for c#, but I'm unable to port it to install4j custom code:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14906/Open-Windows-Firewall-During-Installation

Perhaps someone has an idea or alternate solution?

Comment: Windows firewall actions are planned for install4j 6, at the current time this feature is not available.

Comment: That's awesome to hear Ingo!!

Comment: Install4j 6 still doesn't have it ;-(

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since the question was asked, but here's how I did it with install4j 5.1/6.1

For every firewall rule I used the "run executable or batch file" action with the following parameters:

Executable: `${installer:sys.system32Dir}\netsh.exe`

Working Directory: `${installer:sys.system32Dir}`

Arguments: depending on the rule I wanted to create using the [netsh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) syntax.

For example: `advfirewall; firewall; add; rule; name=${compiler:sys.shortName} UDP IN; dir=in; action=allow; service=${compiler:sys.shortName}; localip=any; remoteip=any; localport=any; remoteport=any; protocol=udp; interfacetype=any; security=notrequired; edge=no; profile=any; enable=yes`

or, from the edit dialog:

```
advfirewall
firewall
add
rule
name=${compiler:sys.shortName} UDP IN
dir=in
action=allow
service=${compiler:sys.shortName}
localip=any
remoteip=any
localport=any
remoteport=any
protocol=udp
interfacetype=any
security=notrequired
edge=no
profile=any
enable=yes
```

A word of advice:

netsh is finicky with regard to the parameters it receives. And even worse, it tends to print very unhelpful and misleading messages when it fails to parse your input. So note the following:

1. Pass each netsh command as a separate argument. In the property sheet separate them using semicolons. In the edit dialog separate by newlines.
2. Don't use quotes in your arguments. If the Microsoft documentation tells you to specify a rule name like this: `name="rule name"`, then do that in the command line only. From install4j, the argument should be `name=rule name` **without quotes**.
3. Make sure that your arguments don't contain anything they shouldn't, **like white spaces in places where they don't belong**. netsh doesn't like that.

Comment: Thx, I found a similar solution, I just created a "firewall.cmd" with the rules let it run from install4j during install.

Answer (score 1):

Thx, I found a similar solution, I just created a "firewall.cmd" with the rules let it run from install4j during install.
Content of "firewall.cmd":

```
netsh.exe advfirewall firewall delete rule name="QOMET-IN"
netsh.exe advfirewall firewall delete rule name="QOMET-OUT"
netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="QOMET-IN" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=3050,29418-29430,14416 security=notrequired action=allow profile=any enable=yes
netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="QOMET-OUT" protocol=TCP dir=out remoteport=3050,29418-29430,14416,20,21,25,587,80 security=notrequired action=allow profile=any enable=yes
```