# How to create a Windows 10 Defender firewall rule with install4j?

Tags: install4j

My Java app needs to communicate through a specific TCP port. I would like the installer to add a Windows Defender Firewall rule to allow intranet communication through that port. How can I do this with install4j?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Howto open firewall ports during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051371/howto-open-firewall-ports-during-installation)

Comment: @Ouroborus, no, that question was for much older versions of install4j. v8 is out already and I was wondering if that feature has been added yet.

Comment: Did you look at the answers? [One of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25550927/367865) was given after the feature was added and goes into how to configure it.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the answers. The one you are referring to is using a batch script, which is a workable option, but I was wondering if there was built-in support from install4j for this as well (without having to go the batch file route). The author mentioned that "Windows firewall actions are planned for install4j 6", but I could not find any mention of it in the release notes of install4j 6-8.